# Creating and executing the function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, function, datetime

Im trying to complete this function that will take an input date and return a date that is a Sunday 3 weeks ago. 
For example: If my input date is 5/25/2016, then the result should be 5/1/2016
I have put together most of the function, just stumped as to what to do next.

```
 IF OBJECT_ID (N'dbo.ufnSundayThreeWeeksBack', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION ufnSundayThreeWeeksBack;
 GO
 CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnSundayThreeWeeksBack(@SOMEDATE datetime)
 RETURNS date 
AS 

BEGIN
    IF @SOMEDATE IS NULL
        RETURN NULL;
    DECLARE @result date;
    SELECT @result = DATEADD(WEEK, -7, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @SOMEDATE), @SOMEDATE))
    RETURN @result;
END;
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.ufnSundayThreeWeeksBack', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
DROP FUNCTION ufnSundayThreeWeeksBack;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnSundayThreeWeeksBack ( @SOMEDATE DATETIME )
RETURNS DATE
 AS
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @DateMinus3Weeks DATE = DATEADD(WEEK, -3, @SOMEDATE);
    RETURN DATEADD(DAY, -(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @DateMinus3Weeks)-1), @DateMinus3Weeks);
  END;
GO
```

Basically subtracting 3 weeks from the given date and then subtracting the weekdaynumber to get to the sunday.